# Is it a fixed or random effect?

Tags: mixed-model

My design goes like this: I have 1 treatment and one control, organized in 3 blocks, each have 1 site of control and 1 site of treatment, each site have 2 subsites, and I sampled 6 quadrats per subsites: 3 under tree canopy, 3 outside tree canopy.
This is a repeated measure experiment, with the same sampling method every year.
I am interested in comparing treatment vs control over time.

My model goes like this: `lmer(Y ~ Time * Treatment + (1 | Block) + (1 | Site / Subsite))`. But I am not sure how to classify the canopy component. Should I include it as a random effect nested in subsite as `(1 | Site / Subsite / Canopy)` or on its own as `(1 | Canopy)` or as a fixed effect?
(Or can I not include it in the model as I am not interested in it??)

Answer (score 0):

I would say use it as a fixed effect, because:

1. With only two levels, you don't have enough data for adding it as a random effect.
2. Don't know about your particular case, but it sounds quite likely that the `Canopy` will have effect on the response variable. Is it the case? In such case it makes perfect sense to include it in the model as a fixed effect. If the canopy has any significant effect on the `Y`, then you should include it in the model since it can help you to explain more variability by the other covariates as well.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!